# Error con pandas al transformar archivo csv a sql ( df.to_sql(ruta) TypeError: to_sql() missing 1 required positional argument: 'con') aparece error

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'C:/Users/salva/Desktop/train.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(url)

ruta = 'C:/Users/salva/Desktop/Titanic.sql'

df.to_sql(ruta)
```

al usar este codigo al sencillo aparece el siguiente error

```
df.to_sql(ruta)
TypeError: to_sql() missing 1 required positional argument: 'con'
```

Comment: Necesitas pasarle el parámetro `conn` que es el motor de base de datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al usar `df.to_sql` se necesita especificar el parámetro `con`. Comúnmente se usa Sqlalchemy ya que es compatible con muchos módulos de python. La propia documentación de pandas nos dice como hacerlo, que es creando una base de datos y cargarla a memoria

```py
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
#creamos el motor 
engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=False)

url = 'C:/Users/salva/Desktop/train.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url) 
ruta = 'C:/Users/salva/Desktop/Titanic.sql'
df.to_sql(ruta, con=engine)
```